# how i get value for Location when my location Manager and Location Provider is available?

Tags: android

when i debug this code found that my location manger and  location Provider both have values but in onLocationChanged(Location location) method not getting value for location then how may i fix this.

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements LocationListener
{   
EditText editText;
Button button;
Context context;
LocationManager locationManager;
private Location location12;
double longitude=0,latitude=0;
boolean gpsStatus=false,NetworkStatus=false,PassiveProvider=false;
private final long time=1000*10;//every 10 seconds 
private final float distance =5;//every 5 meter

String Provider=null;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    addListenerAction();

}


public void addListenerAction()
    {
        editText=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        button=(Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) 
            {   
                context=getApplicationContext();
                getLocation();
            }
        });
    }

public void getLocation()
    {
        locationManager=(LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        gpsStatus=locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
        if(gpsStatus)
        {
            Log.v("Gps is On","="+gpsStatus);
            Criteria criteria=new Criteria();
            Provider=locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true);
            locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,0, 0,this);

    }
}
@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) 
{
    location12=location;
    if(locationManager !=null && Provider !=null && location12 !=null)
    {
        Location s=location;
  // here i did not value. how may i resolve it.    
                  location=locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(Provider);

                if(s !=null)
                    {
                        latitude=location.getLatitude();
                        longitude=location.getLongitude();
                        System.out.println("lATITUDE ="+latitude + "Longitude ="+longitude);
                    }
    }

}


@Override
public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {

}


@Override
public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {


}


@Override
public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {


}
 }
```

My i used these permissions.

```
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_MOCK_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INSTALL_LOCATION_PROVIDER"/>
```

But i am not getting success to get value for location.

Comment: please tell me answer.

Comment: Where are you running this code ? in Emulator or in Device ?

Comment: i am running this code in device.

Comment: ok, and Is your device under open sky or inside the office room ?

Comment: `GPS_PROVIDER` requires open sky or near window location only. take your device outside the office and run your application. It will surely run, there is no error in your code.

Comment: @user3509581, any progress ?

Comment: no my code its not work

Comment: And i did not get any value for location

Comment: any error or "application stop working" like case ?

Comment: i used out side of my office but not show location

Comment: no i did not get any error

Comment: but some times it shows java .lang. illagle  exception

Comment: How are you accessing Internet in your device, using WifI or using 3G ?

Comment: now it shows me loction

Comment: ha ha..... good enjoy then :)

Comment: i think its network or device accessing problem

Comment: See if your device is using Wifi, and you are out of range then it will not fetch GPS.

Comment: ok  i will aware next time all things u told me.

Answer (score 0):

This is very tough case to get Exact Location. If you use the below codes then you will get Exact Location.

Need to do:

1. You need to have Google playservice Lib project which will be available in sdk examples.
2. Copy Paste this Class.

public class Ex extends Activity implements  LocationListener,    GooglePlayServicesClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
      GooglePlayServicesClient.OnConnectionFailedListener{

```
private Location location;
private LocationRequest mLocationRequest;
private LocationClient mLocationClient;

private int UPDATE_INTERVAL_IN_MILLISECONDS = 0;
private int FAST_INTERVAL_CEILING_IN_MILLISECONDS = 0;
private final static int CONNECTION_FAILURE_RESOLUTION_REQUEST = 20000;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle arg0) {
    super.onCreate(arg0);
    setContentView(R.layout.sample);
    mLocationRequest = LocationRequest.create();
    mLocationRequest.setInterval(UPDATE_INTERVAL_IN_MILLISECONDS);
    mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
    mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(FAST_INTERVAL_CEILING_IN_MILLISECONDS);

    mLocationClient = new LocationClient(this, this, this);
    mLocationClient.connect();


}




@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
    /*
     * Google Play services can resolve some errors it detects. If the error
     * has a resolution, try sending an Intent to start a Google Play
     * services activity that can resolve error.
     */
    if (connectionResult.hasResolution()) {
        try {
            // Start an Activity that tries to resolve the error
            connectionResult.startResolutionForResult( this,CONNECTION_FAILURE_RESOLUTION_REQUEST);
        } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e) {
            // Log the error
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } else {
        // If no resolution is available, display a dialog to the user with
        // the error.

    }
}

/*
 * This is overridden method of interface
 * GooglePlayServicesClient.ConnectionCallbacks which is called when
 * locationClient is connected to google service. You can receive GPS
 * reading only when this method is called.So request for location updates
 * from this method rather than onStart()
 */
@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle arg0) {
    mLocationClient.requestLocationUpdates(mLocationRequest, this);
}

@Override
public void onDisconnected() {
    stopGPS();
}

/*
 * Overridden method of interface LocationListener called when location of
 * gps device is changed. Location Object is received as a parameter. This
 * method is called when location of GPS device is changed
 */
@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    if (location != null) {
        this.location=location;
        stopGPS();
    }
}

/*
 * Called when Service running in background is stopped. Remove location
 * Update to stop receiving GPS reading
 */
public void stopGPS() {
    try{
        if(mLocationClient!=null){
            if(mLocationClient.isConnected()){
                mLocationClient.removeLocationUpdates(this);
                mLocationClient=null;
            }else{
                mLocationClient=null;
            }
        }
        if(mLocationRequest!=null){
            mLocationRequest=null;
        }
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    stopGPS();
    super.onDestroy();
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    stopGPS();
    super.onBackPressed();
}
}
```

NOte: You need Google Play Service Library as a added Project. Enable GPS and then Chenck,.. and Below Permissions:

```
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION_EXTRA_COMMANDS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_GPS" />
```